# How can I update a home application without being asked to redefine the default home?

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I have developed an application set as a home onto my Android device. On my device I set it as the default home application. That way, each time I click the home button, I am redirected to this app.

The problem I have is that I have to produce some updates. But when the app has been updated, the device ask to define the default home once anew.

I would like the update to be performed without the user having to define the default home again.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a way to do this. Each time your app is updated the user will have the opportunity to chose whether they want to keep it as the default home application. It is a means of Android showing a user he or she is in control of there device at all times.

If im wrong someone please correct me.

Comment: If I uninstall the home pre-installed on the device, and by the way, if I only have one home on the device(mine), would it work?

Comment: It may work if you uninstall the home pre-installed even though i wouldnt recomment this. Its work a try.